# Get all connected iOS devices info using mac app

Tags: swift, macos

I want to create a swift function which gets info(name, UDID etc) of  all tethered iOS devices connected to mac. So far I am unable to find any help in this.

Edit:

I installed mobiledevice framework and wrote a function which is:

```
func getConnectedDevices(lblOut: NSTextView)
{
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments = ["--login", "-c", "\"mobiledevice get_device_prop DeviceName\""]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    lblOut.string += "\n" + String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)!

}
```

Above function gives output that command not found but running the same command in terminal gives me desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get information through using MobileDevice.framework i have shared some demo examples written in Objective C and its same functionality on GNU/Linux and Mac OS/X :

Here is the info and examples Library Interfaces [link](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library)

Here is [link](https://github.com/h3adshotzz/DeviceUtilz) for github demo for objective C

Command line utility for interacting with Apple's Private Mobile Device Framework for OS/X : [link](https://github.com/samdmarshall/SDMMobileDevice)

Comment: I edited the question, Can you guide me through this one?